# Opencart: Unserialized error after editing db directly

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Opencart version: 2.0.1.1

I am getting unserialized error after editing a html section url in oc_module database table

`PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 378 of 378  bytes in /catalog/model/extension/module.php on line 7 url: / referal: http://www.xxxxx.com/ Array`

`[EDIT]` I changed from `src=&quot;image/` to `src=&quot;https://www.xxxxxx.com/image/` `[EDIT ENDS]`

Here is what I tried:

1) I restored back the oc_module table before the change.

2) Cleared the cache.

3) Also i saw that there were some modules in oc_setting table where `serialized = 1` so i changed to `serialized=0`

but it didn't solve the issue.

Any idea how to solve this. Just editing one url caused this issue.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Revert to your database backup - php serialization includes string length in its data - changing a string without updating the length will cause these type of errors

Comment: I did restore the backup. Also changed the type of column from text to longtext. But still getting those errors.

Comment: I did change the string length of many modules but i think i editted a lot of them so i just deleted html modules and recreated them which solved the issue.